# How to send "event_time" for the Firebase Cloud Messaging in JSON object?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, timestamp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notification for android some minutes after an event in my DB. I send a JSON Object for the FCM with date at format RC3339 UTC in the "event_time" key like firebase documentation, but in my app arrive the notification with date of 1970. Firebase documentation say this key should be send like timestamp at format "2020-06-16T20:10:15Z", but it doesn't work. I did some tests with other date, but I didn't understand what happens wrong. Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase Support answer "event-time" is a bug. We have to fix it with some code in backend.

Comment: Could you share the support answer or tell us what you had to do to fix it? I'm currently having the same issue.